# INTENT not getting called with training phrases

Tags: firebase, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have total 4 Dialogflow Intents. They are

1. Default Welcome Intent ( Events: Welcome, webhook call enabled )
2. Default Fallback Intent ( Default Fallback Intent: Enabled, webhook call disabled )
3. goodbye ( Events: actions_intent_CANCEL, intent as end of conv: enabled )
4. astro (webhok call enabled)

intent named "**astro**" contains 5 training phrases and its events field is empty. Upon calling out any one phrase from the 5 specified it should respond with normal Text response. As of know I tried using all the 5 phrases and it invokes only "Default Fallback Intent". Below is the small glimpse of my code (index.js)

```
.
.
.
function welcome(agent) {
  var request = require('request');
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                request(options, (error, response, body) => {
          });

  }

  function astro(agent) {
  var request = require('request');
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          request(astro_options, (error, response, body) => {
      });
  }

let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
intentMap.set('astro', astro);
agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question a bit? I will need to see your training phrases, user query & error that you're receiving.

Comment: No I don't have any errors but what i want is when i call my "Display Name" with training phrase, that intent with the respective phrase should be invoked. For example I have an intent "A" with training phrase "capital" and its not the welcome intent, so When i say Hey Google Talk to My display name for capital then A should be invoked.

Comment: Have you made sure that for each intent where you'll be relying on fulfillment that you've enabled the toggle `Enable webhook call for this intent`?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a followup intent of the parent solved the problem. Suggestions are still open but this worked for me.

Comment: It seems a vague reason to me. It should invoke your intent even if you haven't added followup intent / contexts. Api.ai tries to find a match between user query with traning phrases & finds a confidence score. If it is greater than a threshold, it will repond you with response you have added. There must be something wrong with your training.

Comment: @TejasBramhecha Thank you so much commenting. I tried saying the exact same phrase as defined in Training of the intent but its not getting invoked. What I really want is when I call my display name with training phrase of other intent it should invoke that other intent rather than the welcome intent.

Answer (score 0):

So I faced the same issue and I resolved it so I am going to recommend you the same solution maybe it works for you if you are making the same mistake.
So before giving input always keep an eye on the context section of the intent you are trying to test.
It might have some input context, if it does, you need to first use that then you can proceed with the current intent.

For example: you have an intent -> "goodbye", and within this goodbye intent you are having an input context of "welcomeContext".
So now if you directly start with the phrases of goodbye intent it will throw back a default fallback intent.
What you should do is, send a Hi and use welcomeContext intent and then proceed with goodbye intent, this way it should work, and it worked for as I have just started with dialogflow I made this silly mistake and came to know this thing.
let me know if it works for you or not.